# How to sign in with GitHub in Heroku application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, devise, omniauth

I want to sign in with GitHub on my Heroku application. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[Here a very clear step by step guide](https://salmaeng71.medium.com/devise-authentication-guide-with-github-omniauth-for-rails-application-220aa52d5b82) on how to implement omniauth via github.